# If I have Friend I can add him again Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, friend-function

I have a little problem. I created migration, model, etc about Friend, when I add Friend, everything is ok, but I do not know how to do that for a particular user in your friends, then I can not add it again. Then simply do not see the button.

This is my button:

```
@if($user->off_friends != 1)
    @if(!\Auth::guest() && $user->id != \Auth::id())
        @if($user->hasFriend($user->id))
            {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'post', 'route' => array('store.friend', $user->id))) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('friend_id', $user->id) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('friend_name', $user->name) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('friend_avatar', $user->avatar) !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Dodaj znajomego', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}<BR />
        @endif
    @endif
@endif
```

And this is my function:

```
public function hasFriend($id)
    {
        foreach($this->friend as $friend)
        {
            if(\Auth::id() == $friend->user_id && $friend->friend_id == $id)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

I waiting for the answer, this is important, thanks!

**EDIT::**
User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
AuthorizableContract,
CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'password', 
        'avatar', 
        'age', 
        'sex', 
        'signature', 
        'skype', 
        'facebook', 
        'twitter', 
        'xfire', 
        'steam', 
        'origin', 
        'duty',
        'off_messages',
        'off_comments',
        'off_friends',
        'off_online'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Player');
    }

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }

    public function change()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Change');
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group) 
        {
            if ($group->id == 1) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isMod()
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group) 
        {
            if ($group->id == 2) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isGm()
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group) 
        {
            if ($group->id == 3) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function isBanned()
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group)
        {
            if($group->id == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasFriend($id)
    {
        foreach($this->friend as $friend)
        {
            if(\Auth::id() == $friend->user_id && $friend->friend_id == $id)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    /*With group user*/
    public function linkName($id, $name)
    {

        foreach($this->group as $group)
        {
            if($group->id == 1)
            {
                $nick = "<td class='info'><a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a></td><td class='info'>".$group->name."</td>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 2)
            {
                $nick = "<td class='info'><a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a></td><td class='info'>".$group->name."</td>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 3)
            {
                $nick = "<td class='info'><a style='color:#eac91d; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a></td><td class='info'>".$group->name."</td>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 4)
            {
                $nick = "<td class='info'><a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id."><s>".$name."</s></a></td><td class='info'>".$group->name."</td>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 5)
            {
                $nick = "<td class='info'><a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a></td><td class='info'>".$group->name."</td>";
                return $nick;
            }
        }    
    }

    /*Without group user*/
    public function formatLinkName($id, $name)
    {

        foreach($this->group as $group)
        {
            if($group->id == 1)
            {
                $nick = "<a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 2)
            {
                $nick = "<a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 3)
            {
                $nick = "<a style='color:#eac91d; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 4)
            {
                $nick = "<a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id."><s>".$name."</s></a>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 5)
            {
                $nick = "<a style='color:".$group->color_name."; font-weight:bold' href=".'/profile/'.$id.">".$name."</a>";
                return $nick;
            }
        }            
    }

    public function showName($name)
    {

        foreach($this->group as $group)
        {
            if($group->id == 1)
            {
                $nick = "<strong><font color=".$group->color_name.">".$name."</font></strong>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 2)
            {
                $nick = "<strong><font color=".$group->color_name.">".$name."</font></strong>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 3)
            {
                $nick = "<font color='#eac91d'>".$name."</font></strong>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 4)
            {
                $nick = "<font color=".$group->color_name."><s>".$name."</s></font></strong>";
                return $nick;
            }

            if($group->id == 5)
            {
                $nick = "<font color=".$group->color_name."><b>".$name."</b></font></strong>";
                return $nick;
            }

        }
    }

    public function showACP()
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group)
        {
            if($group->id == 1)
            {
                $show = '<li><a href="/admin">ACP</a></li>';
                return $show;
            }
        }
    }

    public function info()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Info');
    }

    public function formatSex($sex)
    {
        if($this->sex == 0)
        {
            $showsex = 'Mężczyzna';
            return $showsex;
        }
        else
        {
            $showsex = 'Kobieta';
            return $showsex;
        }
    }

    public function note()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Note');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact');
    }

    public function checkGroup($id)
    {
        foreach($this->group as $group) 
        {
            if ($group->id == 1) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function queryComment($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('to_user', $id);
    }

    public function queryCommit($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('to_comment', $id);
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }

    public function friend()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend');
    }

    public function queryFriend($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->where('friend_id', $id);
    }
}
```

Friend Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Friend extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['friend_id', 'friend_name', 'added_at', 'friend_avatar'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**ADDING ANSWER:**

I did it like that:

```
@if(!\Auth::guest() && $user->id != \Auth::id() && !\Auth::user()->hasFriend($user->id))

     BUTTON

@endif
```

Comment: can you post your User and Friend models?

Comment: I added it to main post, look at this and if you could, help me with this!

Comment: Heloo, this is important, could someone help me please?